# Display Images From Array of String URL's in ListView in Android Studio using Picasso

Tags: android, listview, picasso

I am attempting to load an a listview that contains text and an image using picasso. I'm attempting to load the images using from their respective URL's that are in a string array. The text portion is loading in the listView. However, the images are not loading so all i get is a listView with the texts in their respective rows but no images. How can I do this by using Picasso? Thanks in advance!

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> {
    Context context;
    String[] descriptionArray;
    String[] url;
    MyAdapter (Context c, String[] importerArray,String[] url) {
        super(c, R.layout.content_orders,R.id.textView2, importerArray);
        this.context =c;
        this.descriptionArray = importerArray;
        this.url = url;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_orders, list, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        description.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
        Picasso.with(OrdersActivity.this).load(url[position]).into(myImage);
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` why? it makes your whole method's code useless

Comment: @Selvin What should I do then? Return convertView?

Comment: *What should I do then?* read basics about Adapter class ... obviously `Adapter.getView` should: 1. create view if `convertView` is null 2. bind data to the view(created or recycled from convertView)  3. return created (or recycled) view ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your Adapter.

```
........
@Override
public View getView(int _position, View _convertView, ViewGroup _parent) {
View view = _convertView;
ViewHolder viewHolder;

if (view == null) {
    view= View.inflate(context, R.layout.content_orders, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) _convertView.getTag();
}
    viewHolder.description.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
    Picasso.with(OrdersActivity.this).load(url[position].replace(" ","%20")).into(viewHolder.myImage);  //here i'm editting your url, because if your url contains and blank space you can't download image from url
    //for that i'm encoding your URL by replacing blank space with "%20"
return view;
}
 .....
 .....
static class ViewHolder{
 ImageView myImage;
 TextView description;
 public ViewHolder(View v){
    myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 }
}
```

Hope this will help you.